# .Net Web Reference SSL Error

Tags: .net, web-services, soap, ssl

While using a Visual Studio "Web Reference" to a SOAP service on a server that requires an HTTPS connection I get the error: 
"The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel."

The parent class of the client is SoapHTTPClientProtocol if that makes any difference.

I am not in the position to modify the certificate of the server. Is there a programmatic way to accept the certificate?
Googling around I found several references to the ServicePointManager class but none comprehensive enough that I understand how to make use of it.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/915599

Has anyone else encountered this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try calling this before calling the service:

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = new System.Net.Security.RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(AcceptAllCertifications);
```

And put this callback method in:

```
    private static bool AcceptAllCertifications(object sender, System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate certification, System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Chain chain, System.Net.Security.SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
    {
        return true;
    }
```